# How to initialize object of Project class in java

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to get the active file in intelliJ and have written this code:

```
Document currentDoc= FileEditorManager.getInstance(project)
    .getSelectedTextEditor().getDocument();
VirtualFile currentFile = FileDocumentManager.getInstance().getFile(currentDoc);
String fileName = currentFile.getPath();
System.out.println(fileName);
```

but I don't know how initialize the project object.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Regards, Erfan

Comment: If you are developing a plugin, you can usually get the Project from the context in some way. From where are you calling this code?

Comment: Yeah I am developing a plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the project from an `com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction` implementation, you can do something like this:

```
public class MyAction extends AnAction {
  public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    Project project = e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PROJECT);

    // or get the current virtual file directly:
    e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want get the project from an com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction implementation idont have access to AnAction event e

Comment: From where do you need access to the project?

Comment: from an ordinary function